# Yocto SDK Kernel Source make scripts fails

Tags: linux-kernel, openssl, yocto

I am trying to compile my kernel module using the Yocto SDK I generated via `bitbake`.

The SDK builds without issue, but when I try to run `make scripts ARCH=arm64` in the kernel source directory of my target's sysroot, I get an issue regarding a missing header file:

```
  ...
  HOSTCC  scripts/conmakehash
  HOSTCC  scripts/sortextable
  HOSTCC  scripts/asn1_compiler
  HOSTCC  scripts/extract-cert
scripts/extract-cert.c:21:10: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
   21 | #include <openssl/bio.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:107: scripts/extract-cert] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1096: scripts] Error 2
```

I have `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " kernel-devsrc openssl-dev alsa-dev"` in my image .bb file, which I believe should provide the missing `openssl/bio.h` file, but this does not seem to be the case.

The only way I have been able to solve this issue is to install `libssl-dev` on my SDK machine, but this feels like a workaround, and not the proper solution. My expectation is that when you source the environment from the SDK, it should provide the necessary headers for the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `scripts/extract-cert.c` is compiled for the host environment, I'd rather try appending `TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK` variable with `" openssl-dev "`.

See this question: [TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK Vs TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113300/toolchain-host-task-vs-toolchain-target-task)